# How to combine multiple regular expressions into one line?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

My script works fine doing this:

```
images = re.findall("src.\"(\S*?media.tumblr\S*?tumblr_\S*?jpg)", doc)
videos = re.findall("\S*?(http\S*?video_file\S*?tumblr_[a-zA-Z0-9]*)", doc)
```

However, I believe it is inefficient to search through the whole document twice.

Here's a sample document if it helps: http://pastebin.com/5kRZXjij

I would expect the following output from the above:

```
images = http://37.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lnmh4tD3sM1qi02clo1_500.jpg
videos = http://bassrx.tumblr.com/video_file/86319903607/tumblr_lo8i76CWSP1qi02cl
```

Instead it would be better to do something like:

```
image_and_video_links = re.findall(" <match-image-links-or-video links> ", doc)
```

**How can I combine the two `re.findall` lines into one?**

I have tried using the `|` character but I always fail to match anything. So I'm sure I'm completely confused as to how to use it properly.

Comment: Why don't you post your try with the `|` operator? That would be the way to go.

Comment: Using the pipe `|` character seems to do the trick. Can you edit your question to show how you are using it?

Comment: I think that the philosophical and religious nature of your example links is a reason to use fake urls in your post. However, I don't really care.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in the comments, `a pipe (|)` should do the trick.

The regular expression

```
(src.\"(\S*?media.tumblr\S*?tumblr_\S*?jpg))|(\S*?(http\S*?video_file\S*?tumblr_[a-zA-Z0-9]*))
```

catches either of the two patterns.

Demo on [Regex Tester](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%28src.%5C%22%28%5CS*?media.tumblr%5CS*?tumblr_%5CS*?jpg%29%29%7C%28%5CS*?%28http%5CS*?video_file%5CS*?tumblr_%5Ba-zA-Z0-9%5D*%29%29&input=href=%5Cx22http://assets.tumblr.com/assets/styles/video.css?_v=3e59720929a0eccd0a35c2526d732210%5Cx22%5Cx3e%5Cx3cscript%20src=%5Cx22http://assets.tumblr.com/assets/scripts/spin.js?_v=105ab587312abf0d21a9dd59b0d1f8b5%5Cx22%5Cx3e%5Cx3c/script%5Cx3e%5Cx3cscript%20src=%5Cx22http://assets.tumblr.com/assets/scripts/video.js?_v=245a0db17682c8926a6ea3abc654b1ef%5Cx22%5Cx3e%5Cx3c/script%5Cx3e%5Cx3cscript%20src=%5Cx22http://assets.tumblr.com/assets/scripts/vendor/video-js/video.js?_v=eafbcd94bf558eb9d8d0ef632df97025%5Cx22%5Cx3e%5Cx3c/script%5Cx3e%5Cx3cmeta%20name=%5Cx22tumblr-form-key%5Cx22%20content=%5Cx22%5Cx22%20id=%5Cx22tumblr_form_key%5Cx22%20/%5Cx3e%5Cx3cvideo%20preload=%5Cx22none%5Cx22%20id=%5Cx22tumblr_video_player_86319903607%5Cx22%20class=%5Cx22video-js%20tvp_video%5Cx22%20width=%5Cx22500%5Cx22%20height=%5Cx22400%5Cx22%20poster=%5Cx22%5Cx22%5Cx3e%5Cx3csource%20src=%5Cx22http://bassrx.tumblr.com/video_file/86319903607/tumblr_lo8i76CWSP1qi02cl%5Cx22%20type=%5Cx22video/mp4%5Cx22%5Cx3e%5Cx3c/video%5Cx3e%5Cx3cdiv%20class=%5Cx22tumblr_lightbox_controls%5Cx22%5Cx3e%5Cx3cspan%20class=%5Cx22post_control%20close_button%5Cx22%5Cx3eClose%5Cx3c/span%5Cx3e%5Cx3c/div%5Cx3e%5Cx3cscript%20type=%5Cx22text/javascript%5Cx22%20%5Cx3e%20%20%20%20var%20__%20=%20%28function%28%29%20%7B%5Cx0a%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20translation%20=%20%7B%5Cx0a%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Cx22Cancel%5Cx22%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20:%20%5C%27Cancel%5C%27,%5Cx0a%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Cx22Email%5Cx22%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20:%20%5C%27Email%5C%27,%5Cx0a%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Cx22Send%5Cx22%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20:%20%5C%27Send%5C%27,%5Cx0a%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Cx22Play%5Cx22%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20:%20%5C%27Play%5C%27,%5Cx0a%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Cx22Pause%5Cx22%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20:%20%5C%27Pause%5C%27,%5Cx0a%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Cx22Fullscreen%5Cx22%20%3Cdiv%20class=%22media%22%3E%3Ca%20href=%22http://bassrx.tumblr.com/image/84235445778%22%3E%3Cimg%20src=%22http://37.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lnmh4tD3sM1qi02clo1_500.jpg%22%20alt=%22if%20you%20like%22%20/%3E%3C/a%3E)

Answer (score 1):

If you really want efficient...

For starters, I would cut out the `\S*?` in the second regex. It serves no purpose apart from an opportunity for lots of backtracking.

```
src.\"(\S*?media.tumblr\S*?tumblr_\S*?jpg)|(http\S*?video_file\S*?tumblr_[a-zA-Z0-9]*)
```

**Other ideas**

You can get rid of the capture groups by using a small lookbehind in the first one, allowing you to get rid of all parentheses and directly matching what you want. Not faster, but tidier:

```
(?<=src.\")\S*?media.tumblr\S*?tumblr_\S*?jpg|http\S*?video_file\S*?tumblr_[a-zA-Z0-9]*
```

Do you intend for the periods after `src` and `media` to mean "any character", or to mean "a literal period"? If the latter, escape them: `\.`

You can use the `re.IGNORECASE` option and get rid of some letters:

```
(?<=src.\")\S*?media.tumblr\S*?tumblr_\S*?jpg|http\S*?video_file\S*?tumblr_[a-z0-9]*
```