# how to re.compile(multiple Regexpression)

Tags: python, web, screen-scraping

I use python2.7.11 to do this work, for example, I have two expressions,

```
pattern_movie_name=re.compile(r'<span class="title">(.*?)</span>')
pattern_movie_Englishname=re.compile(r'<span class="title">&nbsp;/&nbsp;(.*?)</span>')
```

if I would like to add them to one expression, how I can do?

```
pattern_movie_all=re.compile(r'<span class="title">(.*?)</span>'+r'<span class="title">&nbsp;/&nbsp;(.*?)</span>')
```

It doesn't work for this!

Comment: There is problem to show my code, I don't know why.

Comment: pattern_movie_all=re.compile(r'<span class="title">(.*?)</span>'+r'<span class="title">&nbsp;/&nbsp;(.*?)</span>')

Comment: pattern_movie_name=re.compile(r'<span class="title">(.*?)</span>')
    pattern_movie_Englishname=re.compile(r'<span class="title">&nbsp;/&nbsp;(.*?)</span>')

Comment: this `re.compile(r'<span class="title">(.*?)</span>')` would match both. Pls provide an example along with expected output.

Comment: Just use the `|` operator. And search for similar questions before asking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24251034/how-to-combine-multiple-regular-expressions-into-one-line

Comment: Sorry, but the questions are almost the same, I am beginner, there is an error when I try that one. So, the answer below is right.

Comment: re.compile(r'<span class="title">&nbsp;/&nbsp;(.*?)</span>|<span class="title">(.*?)</span>')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use alternation operator. Note that the order of patterns is very important.

```
re.compile(r'<span class="title">&nbsp;/&nbsp;(.*?)</span>|<span class="title">(.*?)</span>')
```

If the `span` tag contains a newline character then use DOTALL modifier.

```
re.compile(r'(?s)<span class="title">&nbsp;/&nbsp;(.*?)</span>|<span class="title">(.*?)</span>')
```

Comment: thank you ! This is working, but I find the result is in a tuple, and it's not encoded by utf-8

Comment: That's ok, I have resolved this problem, thanks again!